# Push notification on website using service worker and fcm

Tags: c#, asp.net, push-notification, service-worker

I am new in push notification. I want to implement push notification on my website using service worker and fcm. I have follow this url 'https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/push-notifications/' and create my client application its show notification popup when I allow notification its create endpoint, p256dh and auth key. I have also created a service using endpoint, p256dh, auth and private, public key and send notification. This notification is receipt by client.

C# code for send notification is shown here:

```
var pushEndpoint = @"https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/fOetqkkxzlM:APA91bHASHHThdRC4dDCnZJxAy6ZngUHhxsT9mjF5xuBDpM5kzy-dq2jcbQtsiDcXZ9WcOTE4GWzUZkvGbt3xBH0y61mqbkRVkjvBfvgnUqAGf1hsIrUXpsrl9nfqmrlXx2UFWaTJerC";
var p256dh = @"BHmoaUoqJ6rUitaXj-YvXbuORO_x6lFigO-NV1ceDygb4GhywOw7WIKWOtWqMsVswl8pUCVJrPiNtyVQFirD1oI";
var auth = @"-aFkO3hZKP6u0BZwKRNDiw";

var subject = @"mailto:xyz@gmail.com";
var publicKey = @"BNizeduk-kgre_pz7aj0_t89t-5nvQttzyL17rQfsc7GlOFIfn0qVKyLF81ahCGdsMdhWz-5n_PQavZHywBt9Rs";
var privateKey = @"W21b4Jh9qSoGI7GpKHAq6ikMBjTStiBvQP_wWVvVRqE";

var subscription = new PushSubscription(pushEndpoint, p256dh, auth);
var vapidDetails = new VapidDetails(subject, publicKey, privateKey);
//var gcmAPIKey = @"[your key here]";
string payload = @"{""user"":{""name"":""mohan"",""teamname"":""b"",""email"":""c"",""players"":[""1"",""2""]}}";

var webPushClient = new WebPushClient();

try
{
    webPushClient.SendNotification(subscription, payload, vapidDetails);
        
    //webPushClient.SendNotification(subscription, "payload", gcmAPIKey);
}
catch (WebPushException exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Http STATUS code" + exception.StatusCode);
}
```

My problem is for every client I have to pass I have to pass endpoint, p256dh, auth key. Can I automate it? Like can I get these keys (endpoint, p256dh, auth) for all the users who has subscribed users and send message at one time?

Please help